# need to read text file line by line using python and get users data into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

i need to read text file line by line using python and get users data into a pandas dataframe

i tried below

```
import pandas as pd
y=0
Name =[]
Age =[]
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line =="<USERDATA":
            row=True
            break
        else:
            l = line.split("=")[0]
            i = line.split("=")[-1]
            row=False

        if row == False:
            if "\tName" in l:
                Name.append(i)
        elif "\Age" in l:
                Age.append(i)

        else:
              pass
     else:
        pass

        while 0<=y<(len(Name))-1:

        z={"Name":Nmae[y],"Age":Age[y]}

        y += 1


df = pd.DataFrame(z,columns=["Name","Age"],index=None)
```

files contents is some how like below:
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Manvj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have some logical issues, I have fixed them, I would encourage you to compare your code with mine and then try to see the differences present and if you have any doubts, comment below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
y=0
Name =[]
Age =[]
z={}
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()
        if line ==r'<USERDATA':
            row=True
            continue
        if line ==r'<USEREND':
            if (len(Age)<len(Name)):
                Age.append(np.nan) #only adding once since done at end of each row
            elif (len(Name)<len(Age)):
                Name.append(np.nan)
            continue
        else:
            l = line.split("=")[0].strip()
            i = line.split("=")[-1].strip()
            row=False
        if row == False:
            if l == 'Name':
                Name.append(i)
            elif l == 'Age':
                Age.append(i)
        z={"Name":Name,"Age":Age}
df = pd.DataFrame(z,columns=["Name","Age"],index=None)
```

Comment: thanks for your corrections, but the issue is that not all items are available for all users which leads to different lengths for each list, what actually needed is to fill NA for missed parameter and get an equal length lists

Comment: @Mohamed Are name and age present for all or do you need to push all the elements in the list?

Comment: not there for all, in some cases Age is not present in the user info, so in such case need to push Age=NA for this user